# Como al descargar archivos con Python se guarden en una carpeta y con su formato correspondiente?

Tags: html, python, web, python-requests

Tengo los dos siguientes problemas con mi codigo, necesito descargar archivos que se especifican en `urls = [("RIO230213", "https://www.coordinador.cl/wp-content/uploads/2023/02/RIO230213.xls"), ("RIO230212", "https://www.coordinador.cl/wp-content/uploads/2023/02/RIO230212.xls")]`  ,y que se descarguen son su formato (xls) y se guarden en una carpeta llamada name, pero al descargar estos archivos se descargan sin formato y en la misma carpeta del archivo: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí], este es mi codigo:

```
    import os
    import requests
    from time import time
    from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
    def url_response(url):
       path, url = url
       r = requests.get(url, stream = True)

       with open(path, 'wb') as f:

    for ch in r:
        f.write(ch)

    start = time()
    for x in urls:
       url_response (x)
    print(f"Time to download: {time() - start}")
```

Mi output quiero que sea asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El primer item de cada tupla es el path. Si querés que se guarden en un directorio, debes especificarlo. Lo mismo pasa con la extensión del archivo. Ejemplo de como quedaría: carpeta/subcarpeta/archivo.xls

Comment: @DanteS. Creo que se refiere a los nombres de archivo sin extensión que le deja en el directorio.

Comment: @CandidMoe Yo hablé de eso. Y ambos tienen la misma causa: el path de destino le hace falta el directorio y la extensión. Tal como está ahora, solo son nombres de archivo.

Comment: Subi la edicion de el output que quiero que me entregue el codigo, por si les aclara la duda. De antemano gracias @DanteS

Comment: Subi la edicion de el output que quiero que me entregue el codigo, por si les aclara la duda. De antemano gracias  @CandidMoe

Comment: De nada! Pero... Probaste con agregar las partes faltantes del path como te mencioné para lograr el objetivo de que lo guarde ahí?

Comment: La verdad es que no te entiendo muy bien, debo remplazar 'path'?

Comment: Tus path son los nombres de los archivos. Si no agregas un directorio absoluto (es decir, que empiece con el disco "c:/...", entonces se completa con el directorio de trabajo (que está en la carpeta del programa generalmente). Si no colocas la extensión al final, se considera que se trata de una carpeta o un archivo sin extensión (sin "formato")

Comment: pero el path y url no deben se lo mismo?

Comment: Si pudes, podrias editar una linea de codigo para entender y asi yo poder hacerlo porfavor, de antemano muchas gracias}

Comment: Editar la pregunta respondiendo no sería algo ordenado. Ahora te escribo una respuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la compresion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu código, no existe realmente una relación entre el url y el directorio de destino. Ya que la url lo que hace es darte el contenido del archivo, mas no su nombre ni extensión. El directorio lo preguntas en el primer item de cada tupla

El código toma el primer item de la tupla, que es el nombre del archivo, y lo trata como un directorio:

- Al no ser absoluto (es decir, empezar con el disco, como c:/) se completa con el directorio de trabajo, que suele ser la carpeta del programa.
- Al no tener extensión, se crea un archivo sin extensión (vos le decis "sin formato", pero en realidad, el formato no varía con la extensión.. es mas, incluso podrías abrir perfectamente el archivo sin extensión con excel).

La solución es completar el directorio con el destino y la extensión.

Podrías hacerlo manualmente:

```
[("nuevo/RIO230213.xls"...
```

O programaticamente usando formateo de cadenas:

```
nombre, url = url
path = f"nuevo/{nombre}.xls"

...
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @Dantes S. solucionaste todo y además aprendí con tu explicación. Muchas gracias

Comment: Me alegro que la entendieras c: de nada!!!